# How to get correct position of DrawingImage in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, drawing, geometrydrawing

I have the code:

```xml
<Canvas>
    <Image Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="1" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="50,50" EndPoint="100,50">
                            </LineGeometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

I hope it can be a line start from 50,50 to 100,50, but finally it starts with 0,0 to 50,0
I seems `StartPoint` in `GeometryDrawing` makes no sense?
Does anyone know the solution? I don't want to modify `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`.

Comment: Why are you using a DrawingImage instead of shapes? Drawing a `Line` control would be so much simpler.

Comment: @Clemens well that's just an abstract code, I know shape is much more simple but I need to draw millions of lines on the screen with real time control, that's for a CAD soft, shape is slow.

Comment: Then you should take a look at how to draw in the visual layer. Start reading [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) and [Using DrawingVisual Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx).

Comment: Thank you your solution looks interesting but I hope to get directly help from here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently a `DrawingImage` is adjusted to the bounds of the actually drawn geometry. To get around that, you may replace the `LineGeometry` by a `PathGeometry` that contains the point `(0,0)`, but does not draw it:

```
<GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
    <PathGeometry>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
            <LineSegment Point="50,50" IsStroked="False"/>
            <LineSegment Point="100,50"/>
        </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>
</GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
```

Note that `StartPoint="0,0"` is the default value. It's just here for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good results by drawing a rectangle geometry with a transparent brush around everything. You could do this composing both (rectangle and path) inside a `DrawingGroup`.

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>

                    <DrawingGroup>

                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent"/>
                         <RectangleGeometry>
                             <!-- here you create a rectangle with desired bounds -->
                         </RectangleGeometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>

                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="1" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="50,50" EndPoint="100,50">
                            </LineGeometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>

                    </DrawingGroup>

                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```